# How to extract a day of the month from an RFC 3339-formatted dateTime in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to extract just the day of the month from the dateTime formatted as follows:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', strtotime('today'));
```

But, when I try extracting just the day of the month, I get '31'.

I'm using: `$day = date('d', $today);`
Which, I'm guessing, is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the second parameter to `date()` needs to be a Unix Timestamp. You're passing it string. As a result you get a date of `Dec 31, 1969`.

All of that code is unnecessary anyways as all you need is:

```
$day = day('d');
```

If you're going to only have access to the date string you must convert it to Unix Timestamp before passing it to `date()`.

Comment: +1 .... *Hm...*, wondering if I should start calling your Doctor Date or the Date Doctor, instead of "Father Time" ;)

Comment: It answered just the part about getting the day from the current date. I was looking for something that could be applied more generally for any date I give it, but it's still pretty useful and good to know!

Answer (score 0):

To extract days (or other parts of a datetime), I use the format function:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2000-01-10', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
$day = $datetime->format('d');
echo $day;
```

Use any format form the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will solve your problem

```
$today = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', strtotime('today'));
$day = date('d', strtotime($today)); // here is the difference, 
                                     // instead of $today use strtotime($today)
```